# Submit script data on given url(var = url)

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to submit my script data on given url(var = url).

Here is the code I am trying. I want to send `pid` and `attrib` id on given url.

```
 function addonCart(pid,attrib)
    {
         if(attrib == ""){
             alert("Please Select Attribute Value.");
         } else {
                var url = '<?php echo $base_url ?>cart/addtocart/';
                $.ajax({
                url:url,
                type:'post',
                data:'product='+pid,
                data:'optionsRadios='+attrib
                });

         }
    }
```

Comment: `data: { product: pid, optionsRadios: attrib }` (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#entry-examples)

Comment: how can i submit this on given url?

Comment: Can u please make an <a href="#"> link with post method to pass given pid and attrib value? Is it Possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can do like below example
anchor link

```
<a data-product="13" data-optionsRadios="25" id="gal_id">
```

Then in javascript

```
        $('#gal_id').click(function()
        {
          var pid =  document.getElementById("gal_id").dataset.product
          var attrib =  document.getElementById("gal_id").dataset.optionsRadios
          if(attrib == ""){
             alert("Please Select Attribute Value.");
          } else {
                var url = '<?php echo $base_url ?>cart/addtocart/';
                $.ajax({
                url:url,
                type:'post',
                data: "{'product: '" + pid+ "', ''optionsRadios':" + attrib+ "}",                    });

         }
    }
```

hope this helps

Comment: not submitted. i want to submitted and redirect to given url.

Comment: this is a link <a onclick="addonCart('34','25'" href="#"></a> and redirect to 'abc.com/cart/addtocart/'.

Comment: Can u please make an <a href="#"> link with post method to pass given pid and attrib value? Is it Possible?

Comment: can u get the value in ajax function

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the response.Here are the solution on my way.
Onclick Href link

```
   <a title="Add To Cart" onclick="addonCart('5','10');" style="cursor:pointer" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
```

Here is my javascript

```
function addonCart(pid,attrib)
{
     if(attrib == ""){
         alert("Please Select Attribute Value.");
     } else {
            document.getElementById("append_product").value=pid;
            document.getElementById("append_optionsRadios").value=attrib;
            $('#new_product_addtocart_form').submit();
     }
}
```

And passing this value and submit the form.
submit form look like :

```
  <form action="<?php echo $base_url;?>cart/addtocart" method="post" id="new_product_addtocart_form" name="new_product_addtocart_form">
                        <input type="hidden" name="product" id="append_product" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="optionsRadios" id="append_optionsRadios" />
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function addonCart(pid,attrib)
{
     if(attrib == ""){
         alert("Please Select Attribute Value.");
     } else {
            var url = '<?php echo $base_url ?>cart/addtocart/';
            $.ajax({
            url:url,
            type:'post',
            data:{
               product : pid,
               optionsRadios : attrib
            }
            });

     }
}
```